# document.getElementById not finding element in ASP.NET form

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I am making an ASP.NET webforms page which will display a google map (via the [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple)) containing a series of markers.

It works perfectly if I **DON"T** put `<div id="map-canvas">` inside the `<form>` tag.

But if I move `<div id="map-canvas">` inside the `<form>` I just get a blank page (with no errors).

Looking at the blank page in the inspector, it seems as though `<div id="map-canvas">` is being populated with some the base elements to display the map (except for the markers) but the page doesn't display anything at all.

Could this be caused by the `document.getElementById` having problems walking the DOM due to the dynamically created ID on the `<form id="form1" runat="server">`?

Note: The code provided is just a test page.  Once I get it sorted it will be using an ASP.NET MasterPage.

**CSS**

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

**Script**

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {  
        var latlngCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(30.000000, -100.000000);
        var mapOptions = { zoom: 3, center: latlngCenter }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        var latlngPlaceOne = new google.maps.LatLng(-30.000000, 150.000000);
        var markerPlaceOne = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlngPlaceOne,
            map: map,
            title: 'Place One'
        });
     } 
     google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you post the rendered HTML instead of the ASP source?

Comment: You can add ClientIDMode="Static" so that ID is same at server and client side for form.But with your code the div is not a server control,so it won't be a problem.

Comment: @KrishnanunniJeevan I don't want to use ClientIDMode=Static because the form will be on the masterpage and is used for approx 150 other pages.

Comment: @Schien Is there anypart of the rendered HTML in particular that would help?  I'd prefer to not just dump the whole lot in here.  The Maps API dumps a ton of markup into the target div.

Comment: 5 lines before and after the rendered "map-canvas". Also look for elements with duplicate IDs.

Comment: @Schien map-canvas ends up with about 150 lines of markup in it.  Just looking for dupe IDs now.

Comment: The div with the map-canvas ID is suppose to be an empty container. The map API uses it to inject code. Can you do a view-source of the static code instead of run-time source?

Comment: @Schien The only things with IDs in the rendered output are the form tag, the VIEWSTATE input and the map-canvas div.  The rest is just tons of divs and imgs with no IDs just classes (used to render the map I'm guessing).

Comment: @Schien Sorry, noob question.  How do I view the static code instead of the run-time?

Comment: Judging by your question you're probably already looking at the static source. It's the generated HTML when you view the source of a page. I noticed that sometimes people use Firebug or Chrome inspector, and those markups are rendered by JavaScript. Is it possible that you simplify your code so that it has just the div with the ID? I suspect that there's styling that's obstructing the view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45687/discussion-between-david-haust-and-schien)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried your example and it works with a small modification: it might be just that your form is "shrinked" in size so the map is not visible. I've added the following styles (pretty much taken from [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple) example):

```
<style>
  html, body, form, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I already had that CSS on my page but hadn't posted in the question.

Comment: @DavidHAust then I don't think it has anything to do with `document.getElementById` - I've just copy-pasted your code into the newly created page (clean ASP.NET WebForms project) and it works like a charm!

Comment: DOH, sorry about that.  Totally missed the 'form' in there.  Thanks for your patience.